# QM perturbation theory : When do I have to use degenerate/non-degenerate perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am considering a perturbation theory problem in quantum mechanics. The unperturbed hamiltonian is $$H_0 = A_1 \boldsymbol{B} S_{1z} + A_2 \boldsymbol{B} S_{2z}.$$

The eigenstates of the unperturbed hamiltonien are $ \mid M_1 M_2 \rangle$, where $-S_{1,2} \leq M_{1,2} \leq S_{1,2}$ ($S$'s are spin operators). Here, $A_1 \ll A_2 $. I want to know if this system is degenerate to apply the perturbation theory. The energy of each state is :
$$ E_{M_1 M_2} = \hbar(A_1 B M_1 + A_2 B M_2).$$

(Am I correct ?) But because $A_1$ is way smaller than $A_2$, it means that the energy will have some kind of structure : separated energy levels of order $A_2 B M_2$, and then close to that, small variations around this value owing to $A_1BM_1$.

In my problem, it would be simpler to do non-degenerate perturbation theory. But I have the feeling that it may be incorrect because of the small difference of energy added by the first operator (like : $\mid M_1, M_2\rangle $ and $\mid M_1+1, M_2\rangle$ have almost the same energy, but not $\mid M_1 M_2\rangle$ and $\mid M_1 M_2+1\rangle$), even if technically each state has a different energy.

What should I do ? Thank you for any comment.